# Is there a reliable way to program by using voice command (dictation)?

Tags: voice

I wonder if we can get rid of the keyboard one day. I've tried Apple built in software but it seems to be focused on common textual dictation and not tuned for programming.

Comment: I doubt there is a general purpose solution to this; do you have a particular programming environment in mind?

Comment: Reminds me of a story arc at _UserFriendly.org_. Did not go well.

Comment: While I think this is a really interesting question, I'm afraid it's off-topic on Stack Overflow.